# SQL, replace part of a string with email

Tags: mysql, sql

In my DB I have a column user_email with values:

```
aaa@test.com
bbb@test.com
ccc@test.com
```

I would only like to change part of email address that comes after @, so that the resulting column would have values:

```
aaa@other.net
bbb@other.net
ccc@other.net
```

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I've found following solution that seems to do the trick:

```
UPDATE table_name SET user_email = REPLACE(user_email, '@test.com', '@other.net');
```

Comment: That will only work for domain `@test.com` in case you have `@test1.com` or any other you wont get desired output.

Comment: Got it. All my users in DB have email from one domain and I just needed to replace that with new domain.

Comment: You have your solution then :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and `concat` fnction

```
select concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX("aaa@test.com", "@", 1),'@other.net')
```

output `aaa@other.net`

so for your column `user_email` it would be

```
select concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_email, "@", 1),'@other.net')
```

Comment: The op wants to change everything after the LAST dot

Answer (score 0):

use replace function

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=33c615a216d8e653c17c36bcedc74a81)

```
select replace(name,substring(name,position('@' in name),length(name)-position('@' in name)+1),'@other.net')

select replace('aaa@test.com',substring('aaa@test.com',position('@' in 'aaa@test.com'),
length('aaa@test.com')-position('@' in 'aaa@test.com')+1),'@other.net')
```

output:

```
val             n
aaa@test.com    aaa@other.net
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat
        (substring
          ('bbb@test.com',1,char_length
            ('bbb@test.com')-
            char_length
              (substring_index
                ('bbb@test.com','.',-1))),'net') x;

| x            |
| ------------ |
| bbb@test.net |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You might use `replace`, `substr` and `instr` together as :

```
SELECT replace( 'aaa@test.com',
         substr('aaa@test.com',instr('aaa@test.com','@'),length('aaa@test.com'))
                              ,'@other.net') as result_str;

 result_str
-------------
aaa@other.net
```

or from your table(`tab`) with a column called as `email` :

```
select replace(email,substr(email,instr(email,'@'),length(email)),'@other.net') result_str
  from tab;

result_str
-------------
aaa@other.net
bbb@other.net
ccc@other.net
```

[***Rextester Demo***](http://rextester.com/MJYZ81902)